# Pass Information from IVR to Call Center in SIP Header

Tags: twilio, sip, ivr

We have implemented an IVR system which also redirects calls to a Call Center. The Call Center wants us to send relevant information in the custom SIP Header so that the IVR can pass custom information that will be useful to service the call without requesting the information entered in the IVR again.
             I have tried to find documentation which clearly explains what is needed to be done but have had no luck.

Is it as simple a adding custom headers as SipHeader_X-headername=headervalue as part of the Voice response as mentioned in https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/sip-twiml 
or something else is required like the SIP URL as mentioned in https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip

Any direction/help will be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

UPDATE to question :

Configured an URL in Twilio to direct calls.Using Java based Microservice app using Spring Boot to service the URL calls. The below code snippet contains the Dial to the CSR.

```
String say = null;
Redirect redirect;
VoiceResponse.Builder builder = new VoiceResponse.Builder();
say = messageSource.getMessage("You are connecting to CSR", null, 
Locale.ENGLISH);
builder.say(new    
Say.Builder(say).voice(Voice.ALICE).language(Language.EN_US).build()).dial(new 
Dial.Builder().number(new Number.Builder(number).build()).build());
response.setContentType("application/xml");
response.getWriter().append(builder.build().toXml());
```

Comment: How have you implemented the IVR? Is that done with Twilio? And how are you currently passing the call onto the call center?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are dialing out to a SIP endpoint so your extra parameters should look something like this from the docs you linked to:

```
$dial->sip('sip:jack@example.com?mycustomheader=foo&myotherheader=bar');
```